# How to trim some characters from string in python?

Tags: python

Hello im utterly new to python, i have this code for showing current time:

```
from datetime import datetime
time = datetime.now()
print(time)
```

workes fine but output look like this:

```
2018-04-05 10:55:36.615329
```

how do i get rid of all those "milliseconds"? so output would look like this

```
2018-04-05 10:55:36
```

Answer (score 1):

While `strftime` is probably the way to go when dealing with `datetime`, I decided to answer the general question of removing chars from a string after the dot.

Essentially, this is your string:

```
s = str(datetime.now())
```

This code would remove all chars after the `.`

```
dt = s.split('.',1)[0]
print (dt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime
time = datetime.now()
print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use time as a vairable, instead use any other name for that, you can achieve your output with the following

```
t = datetime.now()
t.strftime("%YY-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```